# Peewee Operational Error in Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-peewee

I am writing a simple social media app using flask python framework and Sqlite as database. But after running the program, it shows the following error. I am kind of confused what is causing the bug.

`peewee.OperationalError: Connection already open`

My plan is to create a login view so that users can enter their email, and passoword to login. So far I've created a view for logging in and it redirects users back to the index page. The above error suggests I haven't closed the database. However, the two functions (in `models.py`) I've written for connecting to, and closing the database are given below:

```
def initialize():
    DATABASE.connect()
    DATABASE.create_tables([User], safe=True)
    DATABASE.close()
```

And I call it in `app.py` by `models.initialize()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    models.initialize()
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

With that the `app.py` has the following methods with function decorator:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    """Connect to the database before each request"""
    g.db = models.DATABASE
    g.db.connect()


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Close the database after each request"""
    g.db.close()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it would seem like a connection is being leaked. You can use `get_conn()` instead of `connect()` and this will ensure a connection is not opened twice.

Comment: From the Peewee 3.0 docs: "get_conn() has changed to Database.connection()"